# React help switching between tabs

Tags: reactjs, dynamic

I need some help switching between tabs. I’ve attached an image to help demonstrate what I mean. I’ve tried many different ways to accomplish this, but I’m stuck. Allow me to explain:

[image of tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7lVf.png)

I have created a json file that holds these 5 tabs in an array of objects. Each one has an id and a name. I am dynamically creating each tab component by mapping through this array within a parent component (the navbar component). The reason I’m doing it this way is so I can easily add more tabs to my .json file later and it’ll automatically add more tab components, without the need to code it in. I want a dynamic solution, **not** a static one.

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Home"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "About"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Skills"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Projects"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Games"
  }
]
```

```
export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  buildTabs = (tab) => {
    return(
      <Tab
        key={tab.id}
        id={tab.id}
        name={tab.name}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div style={style}>
        {TabJSON.map(this.buildTabs)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to set a selected state within the tab component itself, but when I click a new tab, the previous one doesn’t disappear. It will just toggle them on individually, which isn’t what I want. I would like them to toggle selected and then remove that state from the others, just like a tab is supposed to work.

```
export default class Tab extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: this.props.id === 0 ? 'selected' : ''
  }

  tabClicked = (tab) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: 'selected'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div
        id={this.props.id}
        className={`tab ${this.state.selected}`}
        onClick={this.tabClicked}
      >{this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to manage this state from the parent component (the navbar) so I can communicate between the sibling tab components, but I run into another issue. The components all get selected on or off together, instead of independently no matter which one I click.

Sorry for the long message, I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *selected* state must be inside a parent Component. For example, you could add a onClick prop function to your Tab:

```
export default class Tab extends React.Component {

    render() {

      const { id, onClick, selectedTab } = this.props; 

      return (
          <div
              id= {id}
              className = {`tab ${id === selectedTab ? 'selected' : ''}`}
              onClick = {onClick}
            >
                { this.props.name }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then control the Selected tab from your parent component (Navigation), passing the current selected Tab for each one, like this:

```
export default class Navigation extends React.Component {

  state = { 
     selectedTab: 0
  }

  onClickTab = id => () => {
     this.setState({ selectedTab: id });
  }

  buildTabs = (tab) => {
    return(
      <Tab
        key={tab.id}
        id={tab.id}
        name={tab.name}
        onClick={this.onClickTab(tab.id)}
        selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div style={style}>
        {TabJSON.map(this.buildTabs)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have less than 15 rep, otherwise I'd give you a million up-votes my friend! Thank you so much for helping me out. I feel like I tried something similar, but messed it up somewhere. You're the best!

Comment: Why does this work like this:
  onClickTab = id => () => {
   this.setState({ selectedTab: id });
  }
but not like this:
  onClickTab = (id) => {
   this.setState({ selectedTab: id });
  }

Comment: Cause React's onClick method must receive the Function object to be executed when the element is clicked. So if you want to pass the parameter, you function must return another one that will be executed when the element is clicked!

Comment: Thank you for all your help =) That was a great explanation!